# PlatformException(400, HTTP status code error., null)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to download an image from an api, unforunately it showed an error. Changing the url works perfectly. How can I solve the problem? Is there any alternative way I can download this type of image?

Here's the code I am using for downloading the image:

```
_downloadandSaveImage() async {
      try {
        showdownloading = true;

        // Saved with this method.
        print(widget.imageUrl);
        print(_progress);
        //var imageId = await ImageDownloader.downloadImage(widget.imageUrl);
        var imageId = await ImageDownloader.downloadImage("http://wallpaper.pkappstudio.info/upload/47418_animal2.jpg",
            destination: AndroidDestinationType.directoryDCIM
        );
        Toast.show("Saved!", context, duration:  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, gravity:  Toast.BOTTOM);
        if (imageId == null) {
          return;
        }

      } on PlatformException catch (error) {
        print(error);
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just had to turn usesClearTexttraffic to true in my androidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the link itself. It means that the link is invalid. It returned a status code of 400. This is what http status code 400 means:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Credits to mozilla for their great explanation of status code 400: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400

Check this out so you will be able to handle other status codes that you might encounter in the future: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: yes,, i am aware of this error.. but when i use Image.network in the same url it displays the image..,so, if it doesn't occur error while viewing the image then  why its occurring error downloading the image

Comment: I'm entirely not sure how you were able to download the image when you got a status 400 error. I think is showing an image because your app hasn't hot reloaded. Try running flutter clean in terminal and check if the url works.

Comment: Please don't upvote on my answer. I'm trying to get unsung hero badge. I need to get 0 upvoted answers and have that answer accepted. Thanks.

Comment: okey..and i cleaned and relaoded it but still the url is workinh

Comment: and pls edit your edit you answer a little bit. unless the upvote is not setting to 0

Comment: Thanks. I edit it. Can you send me the link? I'm going to check what's happening. It's really weird to get a status code 400 error and still get an image downloaded.

Comment: no.. I meant the url is working in imaget.network().. but not working in image downloader

Comment: That's weird. I think the problem is with ImageDownloader package itself. Have you tried using CachedNetworkImage package? It caches the image and loads that image locally when you try to get that same image again. https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/cached-images

Comment: yes, i have used it to load image. but can i download image using this?

Comment: yes it caches the images. It will download them and keep them in the local storage for 30 days.

Comment: owh.. but i wanted to download the image not as a chaches.. is there any other alternative way to download image?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is another way to download it. I'm really confused how it returned a status 400 when you could load the image.

Comment: i just found the answer..i had to enable the usesClearTexttrafic to true,, and it solved my problem